# navigation bar перекрывает TableViewCell

Tags: ios

Без navigation bar table view cell у  самого верха экрана

[image: Без navigation bar table view cell у самого верха экрана]

появился navigation bar, но table view не двигается вниз, поэтому navigation bar наползает на tableViwCell и перекрывает яейчку, прочитать содержимое нельзя

[image: появился navigation bar, но table view не двигается вниз, поэтому navigation bar наползает на tableViwCell и перекрывает яейчку, прочитать содержимое нельзя]

Comment: Как у вас tableview по оси Y регулируется? Иногда бывает проблема из-за constraints, попробуйте сменить привязки по высоте, к примеру,  equal heigh на top и bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Добавь это в контроллер

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Comment: ну что-то ничего не меняется                                                       self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None

Comment: Ты именно запускал программу? Или только в билдере смотрел?

Comment: смотрел в симуляторе

Comment: через что navigationBar ставил?